# Canvas Rotation

Tags: android, canvas, rotation

Can someone explain exactly how rotation of the canvas about a point works ?

I have lines and I want to draw text parallel to each line. I have worked out the trigonometry required to calculate the angle of the line and it`s centre point.

When I try rotate the canvas about the start point of the line, then draw the text and restore, I am always getting strange offsets which obviously means I do not quiet get how the rotation is working ...

Can someone explain what happens when you rotate the canvas about a point and how the then drawing on co-ords X,Y translates back ?

Comment: Please include your code in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see the following class:

```
class V extends View {

    private Paint mPaint;

    public V(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mPaint.setColor(0xffeeeeee);
        mPaint.setTextSize(24);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        float x = 100;
        float y = 50;
        float dx = 60;
        float dy = 40;
        canvas.drawLine(x, y, x + dx, y + dy, mPaint);
        canvas.save();
        float degrees = (float) (180 * Math.atan2(dy, dx) / Math.PI);
        canvas.rotate(degrees, x, y);
        canvas.drawText("text", x, y, mPaint);
        canvas.restore();
    }
}
```

now i hope everything should be clear how canvas rotation works...

Comment: The thing that still confuses me, if I want to offset the text say to the midpoint of `dy`. If I add `dy/2` to the `drawText` this translates back to a shift in the x co-ordinate in the original (un-transformed) view

Comment: so instead of x use x + Math.hypot(dx, dy) / 2 when calling drawText

Comment: yes x- Math.hypot(dx,dy)/2 does the job ... got it now ... thanks !